# MLE of correlated normally distributed random variables

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution

Consider a random variables $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$, $Y = (Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n)'$, where $E(Y_i) = \mu$, $Var(Y_i) = \sigma^2$ and $Cov(Y) = V = \sigma^2 R$, $R$ is known and fixed.

Find the MLE of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

---

Here is what I have tried, but I am not sure if it is correct:

The log-likehood of $Y$ given $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$
$$
\begin{array}{l l}
l(Y|\theta) 
& = \log \left( (2 \pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}} |V|^{\frac{1}{2}} \exp(- \frac{1}{2} (Y-\mu 1_n)' V^{-1} (Y - \mu 1_n)) \right) \\
& = -\frac{n}{2} \log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2} \log(\sigma^{2n}|R|) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (Y - \mu 1_n)' R^{-1} (Y - \mu 1_n) \\
& = -\frac{n}{2} \log(2\pi) - \frac{n}{2} \log(\sigma^2) - \frac{1}{2} \log(|R|) \\ & - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (Y' R^{-1} Y - \mu Y' R^{-1} 1_n - \mu 1_n' R^{-1} Y + \mu^2 1_n' R^{-1} 1_n) \\
& = -\frac{n}{2} \log(2\pi) - \frac{n}{2} \log(\sigma^2) - \frac{1}{2} \log(|R|) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (Y' R^{-1} Y - 2\mu Y' R^{-1} 1_n + \mu^2 1_n' R^{-1} 1_n)
\end{array}
$$
$\because 1_n' R^{-1} Y$ is $1 \times 1$ (scalar), $1_n' R^{-1} Y = (1_n' R^{-1} Y)' = Y' (R^{-1})' 1_n = Y' R^{-1} 1_n$

$\mu$ part:

$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mu} 
= -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (-2 Y' R^{-1} 1_n + 2\mu 1_n' R^{-1} 1_n)
= \frac{1}{\sigma^2} (Y' - \mu 1_n') R^{-1} 1_n
$$

$$
\left. \frac{\partial l}{\partial \mu} \right|_{\mu=\hat{\mu}} = 0
$$

$$
\implies (Y' - \hat{\mu} 1_n') R^{-1} 1_n = 0
$$

And I get stuck here. Are my steps correct? And if so, any hints for me to proceed? Or are there any other approaches?

The $\sigma^2$ part is fine. Here are my steps:
$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma^2} 
= -\frac{n}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{1}{2 (\sigma^2)^2} (Y - \mu 1_n)' R^{-1} (Y - \mu 1_n)
$$

$$
\left. \frac{\partial l}{\partial \sigma^2} \right|_{\sigma^2 = \hat{\sigma}^2} = 0
$$

$$
\implies \frac{1}{2 (\sigma^2)^2} (Y - \mu 1_n)' R^{-1} (Y - \mu 1_n) = \frac{n}{2\sigma^2}
$$

$$
\implies \hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{(Y - \mu 1_n)' R^{-1} (Y - \mu 1_n)}{n}
\quad \text{or} \quad 0 \quad \text{(rejected)}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the $\mu$ part,
$$
\dfrac{\partial l}{\partial \mu} 
= -\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^2} (-2 Y' R^{-1} 1_n + 2\mu 1_n' R^{-1} 1_n)
= \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} (Y' - \mu 1_n') R^{-1} 1_n
$$
the last equation is not helping. If one takes the second term and equate it to zero, it means
$$-2 Y' R^{-1} 1_n + 2\mu 1_n' R^{-1} 1_n=0$$
i.e.,$$\hat\mu_n=\dfrac{Y' R^{-1} 1_n}{1_n' R^{-1} 1_n}$$
For the $\sigma$ part,
$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n}(Y - \hat\mu_n 1_n)' R^{-1} (Y - \hat\mu_n 1_n)$$
since this is always positive.

Comment: Thanks! I was told that $\hat{\mu} = \bar{Y}$ but I could not get it and hoped to find someone to confirm whether there was something wrong in my steps or $\bar{Y}$ is not correct.